# passport.authenticate() is not being executed via $http.get

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following angular controller

```
angular.module('app').controller('mvNavBarLoginCtrl', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.login = function(){
        $http.get('/auth/twitter').then(function(response){
            if(response.data.success)
            {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

My `routes.js` has the following:

```
app.get('/auth/twitter', passport.authenticate('twitter'));
```

I can verify that I am getting here, however it doesn't seem the passport.authenticate is being executed.

More over if I try to hit the same route from html markup using `(href="/auth/twitter" target="_self")` everything works great.

Any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

just looking at your code without checking passport api. I think passport. authenticate return 302 redirect as response. 302 redirect has empty body. your callback function will not follow 302. when you do this in a link, the browser do follow 302.

Comment: Sounds like you are correct. Is it more the case that angular intercepts the redirect instead of letting the browser to handle it until its done?

Comment: browser should handle the 302, but...you know things like that can happen. look closely at the devtool network tab to see what response/headers you receive.